Jupiter transaction not getting confirmed despite multiple retries
I'm working on a Solana-based application and I'm facing an issue with transaction confirmation. I have implemented a function called transactionSenderAndConfirmationWaiter that is responsible for sending a raw transaction to the Solana network and waiting for its confirmation. The function includes a resender mechanism that periodically resends the transaction if the initial send fails.
However, despite the implementation of this function, I'm still facing an issue where some transactions are not getting confirmed. The code appears to be executing correctly, but the transaction never gets minted on the Solana blockchain.
Here's the relevant code snippet:
 async transactionSenderAndConfirmationWaiter({
    connection,
    serializedTransaction,
    blockhashWithExpiryBlockHeight,
  }: TransactionSenderAndConfirmationWaiterArgs): Promise<VersionedTransactionResponse | null> {
    console.log('Entering transactionSenderAndConfirmationWaiter');
  
    const SEND_OPTIONS = {
      skipPreflight: true,
    };
  
    console.log('Sending raw transaction to the Solana network');
    const txid = await connection.sendRawTransaction(
      serializedTransaction,
      SEND_OPTIONS
    );
    console.log('Transaction sent with ID:', txid);
  
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const abortSignal = controller.signal;
  
    const abortableResender = async () => {
      console.log('Starting abortable resender');
      while (true) {
        await this.wait(5000);
        if (abortSignal.aborted) {
          console.log('Abortable resender aborted');
          return;
        }
        try {
          console.log('Resending transaction');
          await connection.sendRawTransaction(
            serializedTransaction,
            SEND_OPTIONS
          );
          console.log('Transaction resent successfully');
        } catch (e) {
          console.warn(`Failed to resend transaction: ${e}`);
        }
      }
    };
  
    try {
      console.log('Starting abortable resender');
      abortableResender();
  
      const lastValidBlockHeight =
        blockhashWithExpiryBlockHeight.lastValidBlockHeight - 150;
  
      console.log('Waiting for transaction confirmation');
      await Promise.race([
        connection.confirmTransaction(
          {
            ...blockhashWithExpiryBlockHeight,
            lastValidBlockHeight,
            signature: txid,
            abortSignal,
          },
          "confirmed"
        ),
        new Promise(async (resolve) => {
          // in case ws socket died
          while (!abortSignal.aborted) {
            await this.wait(5000);
            console.log('Checking transaction status');
            const tx = await connection.getSignatureStatus(txid, {
              searchTransactionHistory: false,
            });
            if (tx?.value?.confirmationStatus === "confirmed") {
              console.log('Transaction confirmed');
              resolve(tx);
            }
          }
        }),
      ]);
    } catch (e) {
      if (e instanceof TransactionExpiredBlockheightExceededError) {
        console.log('Transaction expired due to exceeded block height');
        return null;
      } else {
        console.error('Unexpected error during transaction confirmation:', e);
        throw e;
      }
    } finally {
      console.log('Aborting abortable resender');
      controller.abort();
    }
  
    console.log('Retrieving confirmed transaction details');
    const response = promiseRetry(
      async (retry) => {
        const response = await connection.getTransaction(txid, {
          commitment: "confirmed",
          maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0,
        });
        if (!response) {
          console.log('Transaction details not found, retrying');
          retry(response);
        }
        return response;
      },
      {
        retries: 5,
        minTimeout: 1e3,
      }
    );
async handleBuyInSolanaConfirmation(ctx: Context): Promise<void> {
  try {
    // ... (code omitted for brevity)

    const signature = await this.transactionSenderAndConfirmationWaiter({
      connection,
      serializedTransaction: Buffer.from(serializedTransaction),
      blockhashWithExpiryBlockHeight: {
        blockhash,
        lastValidBlockHeight: swapResponse.lastValidBlockHeight,
      },
    });

    if (!signature) {
      console.log('Transaction confirmation failed');
      return;
    }

    console.log('Transaction confirmed with signature:', signature);

    // ... (code omitted for brevity)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error in handleBuyInSolanaConfirmation:', error);
    await this.handlerService.handleError(ctx);
  }
}```

```private async getJupiterSwapTransaction(
    quoteResponse: any,
    publicKey: string,
    priorityFeeEstimate: number,
  ): Promise<any> {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        'https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/swap',
        {
          quoteResponse,
          userPublicKey: publicKey,
          wrapAndUnwrapSol: true,
          dynamicComputeUnitLimit : true,
          // useSharedAccounts: false,
          prioritizationFeeLamports: {
            autoMultiplier : 10
          },
          
        },
        {
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        },
      );
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      logger.error('Error fetching Jupiter swap transaction:', error);
      throw new Error('Failed to fetch Jupiter swap transaction');
    }
  }```


This question is similar to: How can I analyze the reason for frequent BlockHeightExceeded errors?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
